# Unable to a function with tensorflow session multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I have a python file which imports a function from another python file which uses a tensorflow session as given below:

counting.py

```
import requests
import time
import os
import tensorflow as tf

# Object detection imports
from utils import backbone
from api import object_counting_api
def count_object():
    input_video = "img.jpg"
    detection_graph, category_index = backbone.set_model('My_graph', 'detection.pbtxt')
    is_color_recognition_enabled = 0
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    result = object_counting_api.single_image_object_counting(input_video, detection_graph, category_index, is_color_recognition_enabled)
    print(result)
    time.sleep(2.4)

while True:
    count_object()
```

The result is calculated by a function-single_image_object_counting from a python file object_coutning_api
The function is as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import csv
import cv2
import numpy as np
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

def single_image_object_counting(input_video, detection_graph, category_index, is_color_recognition_enabled):     
        counting_mode = "..."
        with detection_graph.as_default():
          with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
            # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
            image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

            # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
            detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

            # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
            # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
            detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
            detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
            num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')            



            input_frame = cv2.imread(input_video)

        # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(input_frame, axis=0)

        # Actual detection.
            (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
                [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

        # insert information text to video frame
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

        # Visualization of the results of a detection.        
            counter, csv_line, counting_mode = vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_single_image_array(1,input_frame,
                                                                                              1,
                                                                                              is_color_recognition_enabled,
                                                                                              np.squeeze(boxes),
                                                                                              np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                                                                                              np.squeeze(scores),
                                                                                              category_index,
                                                                                              use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                                                                                              line_thickness=4)
            if(len(counting_mode) == 0):
                cv2.putText(input_frame, "...", (10, 35), font, 0.8, (0,255,255),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)                       
            else:
                cv2.putText(input_frame, counting_mode, (10, 35), font, 0.8, (0,255,255),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)

            #cv2.imshow('tensorflow_object counting_api',input_frame)        
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            return counting_mode
            sess.close()
```

The counting mode returns the count the first time but fails to execute again.
I am monitoring a directory that overwrites it's image time to time.I need to execute the counting.py file once and get the results faster as restarting the python file will take more time as it will start Tensorflow again and again.
If anyone can give a solution to run the function multiple times, it would be a big help.

The output of this is:

```
'defected:': 1, 'perfect:': 1
    (program doesn't end)
```

I have tried to close the session at the end of single_image_counting function but the output remains same.

Comment: Solved the issue from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767184/tensorflow-running-session-multiple-times-in-a-loop

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly has resolved your problem for the benefit of the community. Thanks!

Comment: I have below mentioned exactly how I solved the above problem. Please refer. @TensorflowWarriors

Answer (score 0):

The key is the for loop using xrange while initializing tensors and while running sessions and reinitializing all the variables on every run.

```
  with detection_graph.as_default():
      with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

        # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
        for time in xrange(1,2):
            image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

        # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
            detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

        # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
        # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
            detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
            detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
            num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')            



            input_frame = cv2.imread(input_video)

    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(input_frame, axis=0)

    # Actual detection.
            for num in xrange(1,3):
                print(num)
                (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
                    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
```